# Moving Mouse Pointer

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent, mousemove

I am doing a project on Gesture based Mouse. I am using hand as the object. I have tracked the hand and now I get the co-ordinate of the center of hand-contour. Now if I use that co-ordinates directly, then I can't move the mouse outside the hand-window. I tried using a scaling factor, but then, instead of scaling, the mouse position shifts downwards, but the area covered by new pointer is same as hand-contour window. What can I do for covering the entire screen. I am using Visual C++ 2010 with OpenCV. The code snippet for mouse call and mouse function are below.

```
/*SetCursorPos sets the cursor position at x,y*/
int mymouse(int x,int y)
{
        x*=3; /*I have tried many value for this, like screen size/handcontour window size etc*/
        y*=3;
    SetCursorPos(x,y);
    return 0;
}

/* x and y of hand center are passed as shown below*/

mymouse(mc[0].x,mc[0].y);
```

Update:
 Can I use ClientToScreen () or MapWindowPoints to achieve the same?? if so please explain the same .

Comment: you have to get the screensize first , then divide that by the frame(image) size. that's your scalefacor in x,y for SetCursorPos

Comment: it doesnt work for my case, because i am using coordinates of center of hand, so, imagine a rectangle inside the image, that size should be used to divide screen size. Even then, the scalefactor wasn't accurate